# What is the meaning of unconered?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Gita Chapter 1 verse 17

[Source](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=ro&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=17&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)

> kashyashcha parameshvasaaha shikhandi cha mahaarathaha

> dhristhadyumno viraatashcha saatyakischaparaajiataha

The king of Kasi, an exellent archer, Sikhandi, the mighty car-warrior, Dhrishtadyumna and Virata and Satyaki, the unconered.

Here i'm not getting the meaning of the unconered .

What is the meaning of unconered ?

Comment: It's a typo. Aparajita = unconquered.

Comment: typo by [4 translators](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=ro&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=17&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1).. strange.. or may be translators did the right translation but it's issue during data entry from their book to this site..

Comment: @YDS - there is no English word called "unconered"

Comment: Yes @YDS  written  error by IIT kanpur faculty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

सात्यकिश्चापराजितः (saatyakischaparaajiataha) = saatyaki + sch + aparaajiataha = and Satyaki, the unconered

So, **aparaajiataha** is translated as **the unconered**.

In general words, aparaajiataha means **invincible**.

---

To support this, here are [the alternate translations](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=17&httyn=1&etpurohit=1&etadi=1&choose=1):

- English Translation By Swami Adidevananda:

  > 1.17 And the King of Kasi the supreme bowman, Sikandi the mighty warrior, Dhrstadyumna and Virata; **and Satyaki the invincible**;
- English Translation by Shri Purohit Swami

  > 1.17 And the Maharaja of Benares, the great archer, Shikhandi, the great soldier, Dhrishtayumna, Virata **and Satyaki, the invincible**,
- Hindi Translation By Swami Tejomayananda

  > ।।1.17।।श्रेष्ठ धनुषवाले काशिराज, महारथी शिखण्डी, धृष्टद्युम्न,  राजा विराट **और अजेय सात्यकि**।